# what is correct place to initialize width/height of a WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

am a beginner and until now I've been re-sizing my control in the VS designer, i wonder what is the correct place to initialize a control property.

Comment: sometimes in the designer the controls seems to be aligned properly but when i open the application, first the controls do not fit with the window size and i wonder if there is a way the controls can be aligned if the user resize the window, @RohitVats ?

Comment: In 90%; You don't. Let the [layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do its work.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you want your user interface controls to automatically resize with the parent Window, for instance when the user resizes the window.  In this case, you don't want to specify a hard and fast width/height in your code or in the VS designer.  You would instead place the user control inside of one of the appropriate [layout controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) available in WPF.

There are, however, some times when you want your user control to be *one size* and always one size.  In this case, you would assign it in one of two places:

1. If it's just a single control, then you would specify the "Height" and "Width" properties in your XAML for that control:  `<UserControl Width="100" Height="100" />`
2. If it's a size that might be reused in multiple copies of a user control, then you may want to specify the Width and Height properties inside of a common [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).